# jQuery's fadeTo function makes elements disappear in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

Any idea as to why this is??

Here's the code:

```
    $(".main_search_big_button").click(function() {
        $('.Search.input').focus();
        $('.theme_classic_search-box').css({'border-color': "#0078E5", 'border-width': '3px'});
        $('.container, .theme_classic_footer').fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function() {
            $('.main_remove_button').fadeIn('fast');
        });
```

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Comment: Safari on what platform? I just tried jQuery's demo page with OS X and fadeTo behaved as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.. Turns out, at least in my case, you can't select an element and its "uncle" element and have them both fade, you would need to select "brother or sister" elements.